# Ffmpeg -c copy not carrying over audio track from mkv to hls stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc, http-live-streaming, plex

I am using ffmpeg to create an hls stream. The source is an mkv with multiple audio tracks. I have tried using `-map` to specify the audio stream as well. I also found that when I point ffmpeg to any other audio stream in the file it works. It's just the first audio stream that does not. At one point I replaced `-c copy` with `-acodec aac -ac 6` on the first stream and I got sound which is great but I am only looking to copy the stream and not re-encode it. The next thing I tried was using other mkv videos I have. All are reflecting the same issue. The mkv's by itself play both audio and video fine in VLC. When playing the `output.m3u8` in VLC the option to choose different audio tracks is greyed out. Here is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i "./video.mkv" -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 -c copy -f hls "output.m3u8"
```

I want the audio of my hls stream to reflect that of the mkv source:
[image]

Although what I get returned from the command above gives me no sound and shows me this in mediaInfo: [image]
I've aslo noticed that hls does not support pcm. Is it possible dash could work with this stream because it is pcm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HLS segments can be either MPEG-TS or fragmented MP4. Neither officially support PCM audio, so you'll have to convert it.

DASH uses fragmented MP4 as segment format.